# How to configure multiple UI languages in SonarQube 7.5

Tags: language

We have setup a SonarQube server to analyze code across two teams that speak different languages. (By language here I am referring to spoken language, not the programming language of the projects). I was hoping we could create two logins for SonarQube, which would show the UI in different spoken languages. This is difficult to research, as any search engine results point to setting up/managing multiple programming languages of the projects...

Is what I want to do possible? I have installed the French and Italian language addons, but cannot see any way of enabling them. We are running SonarQube 7.5 on our own debian server.

Answer (score 0):

I found out through the sonarqube forum that it will display in the default language provided by the browser configuration.